# SP-initiated SAML 2.0 POST via a Standards compliant Idp Metadata in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, saml

I want to integrate SP-initiated SAML 2.0 POST. Also, I need to generate Service Provider's metadata for sharing it to my Client. Please somebody have any idea about this. Sample code will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After doing research i found that Sustainsys.saml2 for C# Web API is the best option available, it has almost no coding needed, and it can be easily integrated by configuration in config file.

So, for achieving the implementation, you need following things:

1. X509 certificate, that can be generated by openssl tool, in cygwin. For, your web application.
2. ADFS server via which you do authentication
3. SAML Metadata generate for you application by adding x509 certifcate, that you generated for your application. Here is the website where you can generate metadata easily, https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php.
4. Then add configuration for SAML in web config file. Regarding more info you can visit to https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2.
5. Then add this code to your index() in controller

```html
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var ssotype = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSOType"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ssotype) && ssotype == "onelogin")
{
                    var email = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("User.email")).Value;
                    Session["loginUserId"] = email;
                }
                else
                {
                    var email = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")).Value;
                    Session["loginUserId"] = email;
                }
                Response.Redirect("index.html",false);
            }
            else
            {
                String redirecturl = null;
                var idp = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SustainsysSaml2Section.Current.IdentityProviders.FirstOrDefault();
                var routevalues = new RouteValueDictionary();
                routevalues.Add("idp", idp.EntityId);
                redirecturl = "~/Saml2/SignIn?idp=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(idp.EntityId);
                Response.Redirect(redirecturl,false);
                
}
```